# how to sort a column with different data sets in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a column with values such as

```
title
------
aaa 3
bbb 5
bbb 6
yyy 1
yyy 2
bbb 8
bbb 12
aaa 1
aaa 2
bbb 14
bbb 3
bbb 4
yyy 3
aaa 4
aaa 5
aaa 6
aaa 8
aaa 12
aaa 14
yyy 4
```

I would like my results to be like this

```
title
------
aaa 1
aaa 2
aaa 3
aaa 4
aaa 5
aaa 6
aaa 8
aaa 12
aaa 14
bbb 3
bbb 4
bbb 5
bbb 6
bbb 8
bbb 12
bbb 14
yyy 1
yyy 2
yyy 3
yyy 4
```

I have gone through similar questions asked on stack overflow before and one **very close** solution I found was `SELECT title FROM table ORDER BY LENGTH(title), title` though it did't work for me since it only sorts from 0-9 first for all data sets then the rest follow.
ie.

```
aaa 1
aaa 2
aaa 3
aaa 4
aaa 5
aaa 6
aaa 8
bbb 3
bbb 4
bbb 5
bbb 6
bbb 8
yyy 1
yyy 2
yyy 3
yyy 4
aaa 12
aaa 14
bbb 12
bbb 14
```

Suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You want to order by the date. Convert the column to a date, and then sorting becomes trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string at the space, and order by each part.

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 1), 0+SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', -1)
```

`0+` will convert the second part to a number, so it will be sorted numerically.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b539e0/1)

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(title), title
```

is only appropriate if all the prefixes are the same and you just want to order by a number at the end.

Comment: Quite a good move but then it now arranges each cluster by numbers say aaa 1 bbb 1 yyy 1 aaa 2 bbb 2 yyy 2

Comment: Not really, The format I wanted as stated was `aaa 1
aaa 2
aaa 3
aaa 4
aaa 5
aaa 6
aaa 8
aaa 12
aaa 14
bbb 3
bbb 4
bbb 5
bbb 6
bbb 8
bbb 12
bbb 14
yyy 1
yyy 2
yyy 3
yyy 4 `

Comment: I just tested, it produces the correct result. I added a link to an online demo

Answer (score 0):

You wnat something like this, to split your data in to the two parts, which can be categorized dn the sorted by

You will have to chekc with your actual data, if the substring and the orde4r still fit, that can only you test with your data

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1
>     (title varchar(6))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Table1
>     (title)
> VALUES
>     ('jan 3'),
>     ('mar 5'),
>     ('mar 6'),
>     ('oct 1'),
>     ('oct 2'),
>     ('mar 8'),
>     ('mar 12'),
>     ('jan 1'),
>     ('jan 2'),
>     ('mar 14'),
>     ('mar 3'),
>     ('mar 4'),
>     ('oct 3'),
>     ('jan 4'),
>     ('jan 5'),
>     ('jan 6'),
>     ('jan 8'),
>     ('jan 12'),
>     ('jan 14'),
>     ('oct 4')
> ;
> ```

> 

> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(title1,' ',Title2) title
> FROM
> (
>   SELECT 
>       
>       title1
>       ,Title2
>       ,if (title2 < 11,1,if (title2 >= 11 AND title2 <21,2,3)) orderby
>   FROM
>       (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(title,' ',1) title1,SUBSTRING_INDEX(title,' ',-1) + 0 title2 FROM Table1 
>       ORDER By title1,title2) t1 
> ) t2
> ORDER BY  orderby,    title1,title2
> ```
>
> ```
> | title  |
> | :----- |
> | jan 1  |
> | jan 2  |
> | jan 3  |
> | jan 4  |
> | jan 5  |
> | jan 6  |
> | jan 8  |
> | mar 3  |
> | mar 4  |
> | mar 5  |
> | mar 6  |
> | mar 8  |
> | oct 1  |
> | oct 2  |
> | oct 3  |
> | oct 4  |
> | jan 12 |
> | jan 14 |
> | mar 12 |
> | mar 14 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3818fe997d4ad6d2413590b608432119)*

Comment: Isn't this just a more verbose version of my answer?

Comment: i didn't see you answer, when i looked at it, it was deleted. and i think this is also more detaled, for the purpose, as we don't know teh real data